# Rails has_many :through sum attribute on "child objects" --> SQL Toughy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three, `one-to-many` relationships, a `has_many :through` association and an object with an attribute I'd like to sum.

This may sound silly, but assume for example a baseball-themed app:

```
:league has_many :teams 
:team has_many :users   
:league has_many :homeruns, :through => :users
:user has_many :homeruns
```

What I want to do, on the league `show` page is list each `team` in the respective `league`, and sum how many **feet** in **homeruns** each team has, cumulatively. (`Feet` is an attribute on `homerun`.)

The closest I can get now is `@league.homeruns.sum(:feet)` (showing how much total distance in homerun per league) but I want to do this at the team level, filtered by league.

Make sense? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you add `:team has_many :homeruns, through: :users`, you could then use `team.homeruns.sum(:feet)` to get what you're after per team, right? It would probably be best to move this into a method in your `team` model:

```
# team.rb
has_many: homeruns, through: :users

def total_homerun_distance
  self.homeruns.sum(:feet)
end
```

To then list all the teams for a particular `league`, just iterate through each `team` belonging to that `league` in the view, wrapped in whatever HTML you want. For example, to display it as a table:

```
# views/leagues/show.html.erb
<table>
<% @league.teams.each do |team| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= team.name %></td>
    <td><%= team.total_homerun_distance %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```