# rails database query efficiency with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, performance, activerecord

I have a database with about 1000 clubs and 10,000 users. I need to build a table displaying each club in a row, with columns for number of users, posts, and comments associated with that club. The query I have now goes like this (from my controller):

```
@clubs.find_each do |club|
    @users.where(:club_id => club.club_id).find_each do |user|
         @numPostsByClub += user.posts.count
         @numCommentsByClub += user.comments.count
```

Now I imagine there must be a more efficient way of doing this, as it takes about 90 seconds for my page to load. Is there either a more efficient way to load all of this data, or perhaps a way to run a rake task (I only need updated data once a day) that stores all of this for quick access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the total number of comments by club and the total number of comments by club.

**[counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache)** will help you if you want to have quick answers for questions like:

1. how many users a club has, or
2. how many comments a user has, or
3. how many posts a user has

but not with total number of posts or comments for each club (although it will make your live a little easier).

**Disclaimer**: Do not start implementing the following advices into production without creating a backup of your database and without reading the whole answer.

---

To make your script faster start by adding 2 columns to your clubs table:

```
class AddCommentsCountToClubs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :clubs, :comments_count, :integer, default: 0
  end
end

class AddPostsCountToClubs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :clubs, :posts_count, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

---

For each club:

1. update **comments_count** to contain the number of comments added by users that belongs to the club
2. update **posts_count** to contain the number of posts added by users that belongs to the club

To create a rake task that will update the counters, add a file `lib/tasks/update_clubs_counters.rake` with the following content:

```
namespace :db do
  task :update_clubs_counters => :environment do
    Club.all.each do |club|
      club.update(comments_count: club.comments.count, posts_count: club.posts.count)
    end
  end
end
```

After you create the file run `bundle exec rake db:update_clubs_counters`

Another way to update your counters is to use the rails console and to run the content of the task (only the part relevant to update)

---

Then, for **Comment** and **Post** models, add 2 **callbacks** to increment/decrement the counters from each corresponding club.

For clarity, I will define all the models involved and the relations between them

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :comments, through: :users
  has_many :posts, through: :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :club 
  has_many :posts
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :increment_club_comments_count
  after_destroy :decrement_club_comments_count     

  def increment_club_comments_count
    Club.increment_counter( :comments_count, user.club_id )
  end

  def decrement_club_comments_count
    Club.decrement_counter( :comments_count, user.club_id )
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :increment_club_posts_count
  after_destroy :decrement_club_posts_count

  def increment_club_posts_count
    Club.increment_counter( :posts_count, user.club_id )
  end

  def decrement_club_posts_count
    Club.decrement_counter( :posts_count, user.club_id )
  end
end
```

Now, every time a post/comment is added/deleted the corresponding counter from clubs table is incremented/decremented.

You can simplify your controller like this (with only **one query** you will have all your data):

```
@clubs = Club.all # I recommend to use pagination and not to list all 1000 clubs at once
```

In your view you simply display your counters like this:

```
<% @clubs.each do |club| %>
  <p>Comments Count: <%= club.comments_count %></p>
  <p>Posts Count: <%= club.posts_count %></p>     
<% end %>
```

You can find more details about [increment_counter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter) and [decrement_counter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-decrement_counter) and [counter_cache with has_many :through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256897/counter-cache-with-has-many-through)

Comment: thanks for such a thorough explanation, it makes a lot of sense. I believe everything is working now ( I don't get any errors, and my schema.rb looks properly updated), but I can't seem to populate those two new columns. If I put the code you suggested in a rake task, I get this error "NameError: uninitialized constant Club" on trying to run it. If I put that code in the migration file itself, nothing happens. Do I need to explicitly define Club in some way in the rake task? (also, would def upvote by I can't yet)

Comment: Hey, I updated the post to help you with the rake task.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `counter_cache` option for your `belongs_to` associations. This adds a field to the parent model to cache the number of child objects. When a child object is created or deleted, this field is updated to maintain the correct count.

More information can be found in the [Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) section of the Ruby on Rails Guide.

RailsCasts also has an episode about the `counter_cache` option, with an example implementation: [Example #23](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

Comment: Thanks, I did this following the rails cast, and there is a performance improvement, but not enough (it takes 30 seconds now as opposed to 60-90). I suppose my ideal method would be to do some sort of caching of all relevant data from the db. Can this be done by running a rake task to pull the data into variables and then accessing that data from my controller?  (also sorry I can't upvote yet)

Comment: You should also look into summing the cached counts via sql. Check out this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052191/rails-has-many-through-sum-attribute-on-child-objects-sql-toughy

In your instance, you're summing on the counter_cache fields, i.e. `@club.users.sum(:posts_count)`

Comment: Try adding `includes` - `@clubs.includes(:users)`, it will reduce all DB requests to 2 SQL queries.